# Convert the Powershell script to Python 3

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, python

I'm trying to perform an upload files from Linux to SharePoint using Python. However, I tried a lot by googling but nothing help. At last, I got a PowerShell script that is working. So requesting help to convert the below script to Python 3

```
Specify tenant admin and site URL
$User = "justin.jacob@spidersoft.in"
$SiteURL = "https://test-my.sharepoint.com/personal/justin_jacob_spidersoftin";

$Folder = "C:\Users\justin.jacob\Desktop\New folder"
$DocLibName = "Documents"

#Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site – required for CSOM
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$Password  = ConvertTo-SecureString ‘123@123’ -AsPlainText -Force

#Bind to site collection
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)


$Context.Credentials = $Creds

#Retrieve list
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("$DocLibName")

$Context.Load($List)

$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Upload file
Foreach ($File in (dir $Folder -File)) {
    $FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($File.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
    $FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
    $FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
    $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
    $FileCreationInfo.URL = $File
    $Upload = $List.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
    $Context.Load($Upload)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can hit someone up here to write this for you: [Powershell Convert Python - PeoplePerHour](https://www.peopleperhour.com/hire-freelancers/powershell+convert+python)

Answer (score 0):

You may take a reference of below demo about how to upload files in a directory：

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"D:\d365\SDK\SampleCode\JS\SOAPForJScript\SOAPForJScript"): 
for file in files:
    filepath = os.path.join(root, file)
    print(filepath)

    # perform the actual upload
    with open(filepath, 'rb+') as file_input:
        try: 
            spfolder.upload_file(file_input, file)
        except Exception as err: 
            print("Some error occurred: " + str(err))
```

Complete demo:

- https://github.com/kongmengfei/sharedproject/blob/master/PythonConsole-uploadfileSPO/PythonApplication2/Read%20AndUplaodFiles.py